# Method return type [U <: Record, T <: Table[U]] isn't working correctly

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, slick

I have several DAOs (using [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/)) like the following

```
abstract class SuperRecord

abstract class SubSuperRecord extends SuperRecord

class Record1 extends SuperRecord

class Record2 extends SubSuperRecord

abstract class SuperTable[T <: SuperRecord] extends slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple.Table[T]

abstract class SubSuperTable[T <: SubSuperRecord] extends SuperTable[T]

object DAO1 extends SuperTable[Record1]

object DAO2 extends SubSuperTable[Record2]
```

I'm returning these in the following method - I'm not declaring a return type, I'm letting the type inference engine take care of that

```
def getTable(table: String) = {
  table match {
    case "DAO1" => DAO1
    case "DAO2" => DAO2
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid table")
  }
}
```

I'm trying to refactor the method to return a `Try` object, but this seems to be confusing the type inference engine

```
def getTable(table: String) = Try {
  table match {
    case "DAO1" => DAO1
    case "DAO2" => DAO2
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid table")
  }
}
```

When I'm unpacking the Success on this I'm getting a Serializable, so I'm trying to assist the type inference engine

```
def getTable[T <: SuperRecord, U <: SuperTable[T]](table: String): Try[U] = Try {
  table match {
    case "DAO1" => DAO1
    case "DAO2" => DAO2
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid table")
  }
}
```

However, the compiler is telling me that neither `DAO1` nor `DAO2` match this type.  What is the correct return type for this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your first definition of getTable (without the try) type the definition of getTable2 in REPL and you will get the return type you need.

```
def getTable2(table: String) = Try { getTable(table) }
```

Which is:  `Try[SuperTable[_1] forSome { type _1 >: Record1 with Record2 <: SuperRecord}]`